# Van der Pol system, Master equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, random-variables, markov-chains, monte-carlo

everyone.

Can me help in this problem. Consider vnder Pol system
\begin{equation}\label{Eq1}
    \left\{
    \begin{array}{c}
         \frac{dx}{dt} = y  \\
         \frac{dy}{dt} = -x + \gamma (1-x^2)y
    \end{array}
    \right.
\end{equation}
with initial conditions
\begin{equation}\label{Eq2}
    x(0) = x_{in}, \, \, y(0) = y_{in}.
\end{equation}

Need to define the state vector, the stoichiometric (state-change) vectors for each interaction,
and the propensity functions. Write the corresponding master equation.
This need for Monte Carlo simulation.

Thanks for your answer!!!

Comment: What is "interaction" in this context? What is it you or the task wants to simulate, where does the randomness enter?

Comment: Simulation solution of the van der Pol system by Gillespie Algorithm